# sql server agent job fails while execute

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis, sql-server-agent

I'm trying to execute ssis package in sql server agent job . while start the job am facing the sql job fail. below i attached the screenshot of the error.
NOTE : it is running fine , if i execute ssis package.

Please find the below screenshot for more inforamtion.

[image]

the step -1 details
Date        3/23/2016 1:39:39 PM
Log     Job History (cbr_report)

Step ID     1
Server      CRM\CRMSERVER
Job Name        cbr_report
Step Name       execute
Duration        00:00:01
Sql Severity        0
Sql Message ID      0
Operator Emailed
Operator Net sent
Operator Paged
Retries Attempted       0

Message
Executed as user: CRM\SYSTEM. The package execution failed.  The step failed.

Comment: The screenshot doesn't help at all. Without the actual error message its impossible to help. Configure logging in the job and the package to see what happened. Also check the *package's* execution reports. Not sure if that feature existed in 2005 though

Comment: In the bottom pane of your screenshot you'll see a scrollbar. Copy _all_ data in that bottom pane. Regardless, I assume this is the same solution as 95% of the tens of thousands of existing 'works in visual studio but in an agent job' questions you'll find online and that is: your sql agent (or proxy) account doesn't have access.

Comment: So... in the top pane, click the bottom (expanded) red X. Then go into the bottom pane and copy all the details in there. It's really annoying (and diffifcult for newbies) to find the error in SQL Server but thats how you do it.